# How to animate marker movement from one location to another in MAPBOX iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, annotations, mapbox, markers

I want to implement remote car tracking functionality using MAPBOX where current co-ordinates & angles are coming from web service. I have tried to change co-ordinates of annotation but the movement is not smooth.
How to apply animation for change of co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

The `coordinate` property of `MGLAnnotation` is [read-only](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.2/Protocols/MGLAnnotation.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLAnnotation(py)coordinate). The documentation for this is [somewhat hidden](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.2/Classes/MGLAnnotationView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLAnnotationView(py)draggable) but you may be able to circumvent this by creating your own object which implements the `MGLAnnotation` protocol and adds a setter to `coordinate`.

Alternatively, an [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8378#issuecomment-289450780) on the Mapbox github suggests that you can use a `MGLPointAnnotation`, which has a [read-write](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.2/Classes/MGLPointAnnotation.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLPointAnnotation(py)coordinate) `coordinate` property